# rails 5.0.2 で cgi が利用できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cloud9 開発環境で Rails 5.0.2 を使用しています。
当該環境で cgi の設定ができません。(該当ページへアクセスしてもソースが表示される)

[ここ](http://www.p-nt.com/technicblog/archives/176)を参考にしてservice-cgi-bin.confと.htaccessは設定をしました。
service-cgi-bin.confに関しては、以下が参考サイトと異なります。

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/ubuntu/workspace/<app-name>/app/views/cgi_bin/
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/workspace/<app-name>/app/views/cgi_bin">
```

.htaccessに関してはservice-cgi-bin.confに記載のディレクトリに配置しました。
また、routes.rbで以下の通り設定後、/testにアクセスしてもソースコードが表示されるのみです。

```
get '/test', to: 'cgi_bin#test.cgi'
```

※test.cgiには755で実行権限を持たせてあります。

何かご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授ください。

Comment: `/cgi-bin/test.cgi` にアクセスすると実行されませんか?

Comment: ご指示頂いたURLへアクセスすると以下エラーが表示されます。No route matches [GET] "/cgi_bin/test.cgi"

Comment: アクセス経路は ブラウザ → apache → rails という想定でしょうか?
rails には CGI を実行する機能はないと思うので、
rails へは ブラウザ → apache → rails、
CGI へは ブラウザ → apache → CGI となるかと思います。
そこで、apache の ScriptAlias 設定が生きてくるわけですが、
ScriptAlias には `/cgi-bin/` と設定していますので、
`/cgi_bin/test.cgi` でなく `/cgi-bin/test.cgi` でどうなるかを確認しています。